# Poner URL externa en routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo el siguiente código, el cual no sé cómo mandar a llamar a una URL externa por medio de routerlink.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.items = [
    {
      label:'Uoutube',
      icon:'pi pi-fw pi-home',
      routerLink: ['https://www.youtube.com/']
    }
  ];
}
```

El cual este label aparece como un menú el cual cuando se le dé click este abrirá dicha URL en otra pestaña.

de igual forma intente meter una funcion pero no jalo.

```js
gourlexterna(){ 
        window.open("https://www.youtube.com/", "_blank"); 
    }
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar con esto se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres enviar a un enlace externo no hace falta hacerlo con código typescript, puedes hacerlo directamente en el html. Crea una etiqueta tipo  y pon en su propiedad href la dirección:

```
<a class="enlace" href="https://www.youtube.es"></a>
```

routerLink sirve para enlazar entre componentes de angular, no estoy seguro de que sirva para enlaces externos siempre y cuando no se redirija a ellos dentro del componente al que se enlaza.

Comment: Hola amigo, pregunta y para ponerlo dentro del item?? es que ese label es un boton que parece en un menu, entonces si el usuario da click en ese menu lo debe de redirigir al enlace externo, o como podria poner html en esa parte amigo?

Comment: Puedes probar a sustituir la propiedad 'routerLink' por 'href'.

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de esta manera, por si a alguien más le ayuda.:

```js
{label: 'url', icon: 'pi pi-link', command: (event) => { this.urlexterno(); }},
```